# How to restart tomcat after deploying war file with chef?

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra

I have my own cookbook that downloads a file from an AWS S3 bucket and tries to restart the tomcat service.

I'm using the "official" Tomcat recipe from `https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat`

```
FILE: myapp/recipes/default.rb

include_recipe 's3_file'
include_recipe 'tomcat::default'

s3_file "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT.war" do
    remote_path node['myapp']['packages_s3_bucket_path'] + 'myapp.war'
    bucket node['myapp']['packages_s3_bucket']
    aws_access_key_id node['myapp']['packages_s3_bucket_aws_access_key']
    aws_secret_access_key node['myapp']['packages_s3_bucket_aws_secret_key']
    notifies :restart, "service[tomcat]", :immediately
end
```

The problem is that `service[tomcat]` is not found at compile time (tomcat is referenced in myapp's metadata.rb also)

```
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2015-01-14T00:56:14+00:00] WARN: Using java::default instead is recommended.
Converging 112 resources
[2015-01-14T00:56:15+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2015-01-14T00:56:15+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-01-14T00:56:15+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-01-14T00:56:15+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/cache/chef/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2015-01-14T00:56:15+00:00] ERROR: resource s3_file[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT.war] is configured to notify resource service[tomcat] with action restart, but service[tomcat] cannot be found in the resource collection. s3_file[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT.war] is defined in /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/uaa/recipes/default.rb:69:in `from_file'

[2015-01-14T00:56:15+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the base instance from the default settings, that should be `service[tomcat6]`. The service resource is [defined inside the LWRP](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat/blob/master/providers/instance.rb#L245). This only works because the provide doesn't `use_inline_resources`, so at some point in the future this might no longer work.

EDIT:

The hack I mentioned below.

```
ruby_block 'restart tomcat' do
  action :nothing
  block do
    resources('service[tomcat6]').run_action(:restart)
  end
end
```

or something similar. Notify the ruby block and it will look up the real resource and restart it.

Comment: I'm using the `tomcat::default` recipe which by default has `run_base_instance = true`. Still having the same issue: `[2015-01-14T01:16:30+00:00] ERROR: resource s3_file[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT.war] is configured to notify resource service[tomcat6] with action restart, but service[tomcat6] cannot be found in the resource collection. s3_file[/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT.war] is defined in /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/uaa/recipes/default.rb:69:in `from_file'`

Comment: Ahh right, the resource doesn't exist until after the provider's action is run. This doesn't seem to be well supported by the provider, they don't have a restart action on `tomcat_instance` which is what you really need. You can patch around this with a `ruby_block` if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks!. How should I use the ruby_block? I tried notifying the ruby_block from the s3_file and then firing the service restart notification from inside the ruby_block but still getting the same error... Snippet: `s3_file "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT.war" do
  notifies :run, "ruby_block[restart_tomcat6]"
end

ruby_block "restart_tomcat6" do
  block do
    #
  end
  action :nothing
  notifies :restart, "service[tomcat6]"
end
`